# Create csv with filename, word count and occurrence of some strings in external txt's

Tags: csv, count, directory

i have a directory with a lot of txt files.

for academic propose i need to create a file csv file to work in excel like this:
I need to count the number of times that some words appear in each txt file.

i think that i should use something like "for" but i'm not sure

i tried to use this to access a simple txt file but the total was always 0

```
total = 0 
def check():
    datafile = file('example.txt')
    found = False #this isn't really necessary 
    for line in datafile:
        if alta in line:
            #found = True #not necessary 
            total += 1
    return False #because you finished the search without finding anything
```

print total

The result needs to be something like this:

name_of_file, number_of_words_in_file, number_of_occurances

how can i do this in python???

tks!

Comment: Provide more information about what you've tried and what problems you encountered.

Comment: i've tried to first of all access a simple txt file and count the number of time that a string appears.